# Flutter Build Tiles onTap showing error " undefined name 'context'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build multi level list view, when we tap child items, it should pass parameter to other page named QuizOptionsDialog.

1) I am able to print the root.name using print(root.name); using onTap

2) but when we try to navigate using following code it is showing undefined name 'context'

Full Code and error
`enter code here`[Code page 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Own62.jpg)
`enter code here`[Code page 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aFVT.jpg)
`enter code here`[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aweHb.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:iti/quiz/ui/widgets/quiz_options.dart';

class ExpansionTileDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('List of Question Papers'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => CategoryItem(
            data[index],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Welcome to another flutter tutorial
// In this video we will see how to create a multi-level Expansion List
// First Let's create a class for each row in the Expansion List

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<Category>
  children; // Since this is an expansion list ...children can be another list of entries
  Category(this.id, this.name, [this.children = const <Category>[]]);
}

// This is the entire multi-level list displayed by this app
final List<Category> data = <Category>[
  Category(
    '1',
    'Main Category',
    <Category>[
      Category(
        '1.1',
        'Sub Category',
        <Category>[
          Category('1.1.1', 'Sub-Sub Category', <Category>[
            Category('1.1.1.1', 'Sub-Sub-Sub Category',),
            Category('1.1.1.2', 'Sub-Sub-Sub Category',),
          ]),
          Category('1.1.2','Sub-Sub Category',
              <Category>[
                Category('1.1.2.1', 'Sub-Sub-Sub Category',),
                Category('1.1.2.2', 'Sub-Sub-Sub Category',),
              ]
          ),
          Category('1.1.3', 'Sub-Sub Category',
              <Category>[
                Category('1.1.3.1', 'Sub-Sub-Sub Category',),
                Category('1.1.3.2', 'Sub-Sub-Sub Category',),
              ]
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
];

// Create the Widget for the row
class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryItem(this.category);
  final Category category;

  // This function recursively creates the multi-level list rows.
  Widget _buildTiles(Category root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(root.name),
             onTap: () {
          print(root.name);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => QuizOptionsDialog(category: category,),
            ),
          );
        },
      );

    }
    return ExpansionTile(
      key: PageStorageKey<Category>(root),
      title: Text(root.name),
      children: root.children.map<Widget>(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(category);
  }

  _categoryPressed(BuildContext context,Category category) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (sheetContext) => BottomSheet(
        builder: (_) => QuizOptionsDialog(category: category,),
        onClosing: (){},

      ),

    );

  }
}
```

Comment: While the images are great as they show the entire file, it would be nice if you could post the contents inside code blocks so the code can be copy and pasted. This makes it easier for people to debug the code, and create answers with revised versions, and makes the post much more likely to get responses.

Comment: Updated the contents inside code blocks.

Comment: Can Anyone please debug the code and update the answers.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code changes that should let you access the BuildContext inside your CategoryItems so you can navigate from them.

Comment: Thanks JwildSmit it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CategoryItem class to also accept a `BuildContext context` variable in the constructor and assign it to a BuildContext variable like you did with category, and then pass that context in from the main widget when creating new `CategoryItem`. This will give you access to a context and should allow you to do your navigation.

To do so:

Storing the context in your CategoryItem class so each instance has access to it.

```
class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryItem(this.category, this.context);
  final Category category;
  final BuildContext context;
```

Updating the ListView.builder() to instantiate the updated CategoryItem class appropriately and pass the context.

```
body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: data.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => CategoryItem(
    data[index], context
  ),
),
```

And now you should have access to the BuildContext for your page where you needed it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help